# Any successful examples of rosdep python-qt-bindings on Electric?

Tags: rosdep, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't figure out how to use a `rosdep` for `python-qt-bindings` in Electric on Ubuntu Oneiric.

It works in Fuerte. I define a compatible `rosdep.yaml` stanza as follows:

```
 python-qt-bindings:
   ubuntu:
     lucid:
       apt:
         packages: [python-qt4, python-qt4-dev, python-sip-dev, python-qt4-gl]
     oneiric:
       apt:
         packages: [python-pyside.qtcore, python-pyside.qtgui, libpyside-dev, libshiboken-dev, shiboken, libgenrunner-dev, python-qt4, python-qt4-dev, python-sip-dev, python-qt4-gl]
```

The install appears to work, then fails at the end:

```
$ rosdep install art_teleop
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
#Packages ['python-pyside.qtcore python-pyside.qtgui libpyside-dev libshiboken-dev shiboken libgenrunner-dev python-qt4 python-qt4-dev python-sip-dev python-qt4-gl']
sudo apt-get install python-pyside.qtcore python-pyside.qtgui libpyside-dev libshiboken-dev shiboken libgenrunner-dev python-qt4 python-qt4-dev python-sip-dev python-qt4-gl
}}}

[sudo] password for joq: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-qt4 is already the newest version.
python-qt4-dev is already the newest version.
python-sip-dev is already the newest version.
libgenrunner-dev is already the newest version.
libpyside-dev is already the newest version.
libshiboken-dev is already the newest version.
python-pyside.qtcore is already the newest version.
python-pyside.qtgui is already the newest version.
python-qt4-gl is already the newest version.
shiboken is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
successfully installed python-qt-bindings
rosdep python-qt-bindings failed check-presence-script after installation
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install python-qt-bindings
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31143/any-successful-examples-of-rosdep-python-qt-bindings-on-electric?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably hard to tell w/o throwing more instrumentation into the code, but probably a bug.  A little surprising as the detection code in rosdep 2 is a pretty direct port of the Electric code.  The detection code runs " dpkg-query -W -f='${Package} ${Status}\n' " and simply parses the output.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-04**:
OK. I'll open a defect ticket and we can pursue it there: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3914